# Input Validation and Representation about System.getProperty & mkdirs

Tags: java, validation, input, fortify, mkdirs

I use the following code:

```
    String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator;
    new File(workingDir + "tempDir").mkdirs();
```

After Fortify's vulnerability scanning to obtain the following results: Input Validation and Representation.

how to avoid the problem arise?

Comment: It's possible for `System.getProperty` to return `null`, you're also ignoring the return results from `mkdirs`.  At a guess

Comment: I don't think this issue will cause "Input Validation and Representation".
It looks like the attacker can change a threat of arguments.
Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Probably not, but there is a case there for some more vigilance ;)